# Create array conditionally (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How do we extract the specific field's value from the array (**I want to extract id value**)

```
[
    {id:1, added: true, name: 'Book'}, -> I want to extract id value!
    {id:2, added: true, name: 'Desk'},
    {id:5, added: true, name: 'Rock'},
    {id:3, added: false, name: 'Rock'},
    {id:7, added: false, name: 'Rock'},
    {id:8, added: false, name: 'Rock'},
]
```

and create an array with the values. (**only if the added field is true**)

Expected Output will be `[1, 2, 5]`.

**It will be great if we can catch the edge case when we are getting [] empty array.**

Please feel free to use lodash (if it's faster and simple than vanila javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just can use [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

```js
const arr = [
    {id:1, added: true, name: 'Book'},
    {id:2, added: true, name: 'Desk'},
    {id:5, added: true, name: 'Rock'},
    {id:3, added: false, name: 'Rock'},
    {id:7, added: false, name: 'Rock'},
    {id:8, added: false, name: 'Rock'},
];

const mappedArr = arr.filter(item => item.added).map(item => item.id);

console.log(mappedArr);
```

Comment: Sorry for replying it late. But can we do this conditionally???? Sorry, I edited the question. I think you can solve it like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Add `Array#filter` first.

Answer (score 3):

First [**filter**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) out the items that have `added` as false then [**map**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) across the result to get the `id`:

```
let result = _(data)
    .filter('added')
    .map('id')
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [
    {id:1, added: true, name: 'Book'},
    {id:2, added: true, name: 'Desk'},
    {id:5, added: true, name: 'Rock'},
    {id:3, added: false, name: 'Rock'},
    {id:7, added: false, name: 'Rock'},
    {id:8, added: false, name: 'Rock'},
];

arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if (curr.added) {
        return [...prev, curr.id];
    }

    return prev;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` and check for the `added` property, if it is `true` add the `id` to accumulator.

```js
var data = [ {id:1, added: true, name: 'Book'}, {id:2, added: true, name: 'Desk'}, {id:5, added: true, name: 'Rock'}, {id:3, added: false, name: 'Rock'}, {id:7, added: false, name: 'Rock'}, {id:8, added: false, name: 'Rock'}],
    result = data.reduce((r, {id, added}) => {
      if(added)
        r.push(id);
      return r;
    }, []); 
console.log(result);
```